# Actionscript 3 instance name property not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a class of a movieclip symbol that is called third_scene_border, I create 12 instances of this class like so:

```
public var border_1:third_scene_border = new third_scene_border();

public var border_2:third_scene_border = new third_scene_border();

public var border_3:third_scene_border = new third_scene_border();
```

and so on, I also set the name of the first instance to be "first_border" like so:

```
border_1.name = "first_border";
```

Then when I trace its name I get "instance(some numbers)".

Why isn't the name property being set correctly? Ive done it for a lot of other instances and its working just fine. I am trying to see on which border a draggable object is being dropped.

Edit: When I write trace(border_1.name) I get "first_border", but when I add an event listener that listens for clicks and put

```
trace(event.target.name);
```

in its function, I get instance(some numbers).

Edit: trace(event.target.parent.name); returns first_border which is correct but when I try to trace the dropTarget in the function of a MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP like so: trace(event.target.dropTarget.parent.name), I get the following error: 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at mainClass/up()

Comment: Show at least your code to more understand the situation ...

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find a 100% solution for your case, because you didn't attach the part of your code with adding the event listener. But, I'd hazard a guess, that you should try to use the **event.currentTarget** parameter instead of **event.target**.

You may read more about differences about theese 2 properites here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#target

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget

Comment: Ive tried event.currentTarget.dropTarget.parent.name and both of them return instance(some number)

Comment: This is the correct answer. currentTarget is the object that register the listener, target is the object that was at the origin of the event. They can be the same object or not, in your case they are not.

Comment: @DimitarVelev Please, could you show us the code where you add the listener function, which has the next code line: `trace(event.target.name);`